# Wordpress ACF datepicker fields not working

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I created a "vacations" `custom-post-type` in which there are two custom fields -> "startdate" and "enddate". The field types are both "Date Picker" obviously.

But for some reason I dont know, I'm not able to fetch these fields. It returns nothing or null.
In my `functions.php` I have this:

```
function get_vacation_dates(){
  $startDate = get_field('vacation_start', false, false);
  $endDate = get_field('vacation_end', false, false);

  $start_date = new DateTime($startDate);
  $end_date = new DateTime($endDate);

  $args = array(
    'post_type' => array('ferieperioder'),
    'post_status' => array('publish'),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post__in' => $post->ID,
     'meta_key' => array(
        'key' => 'vacation_start',
        'value' => $startDate
     ),
     array(
        'key' => 'vacation_end',
        'value' => $endDate
     )      
  );

  $query = new WP_Query($args);

  echo json_encode($query);
  die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_vacation_dates', 'get_vacation_dates');
add_action('wp_ajax_get_vacation_dates','get_vacation_dates');
```

I don't know if this is correct at all, since I want to get each vacation_period (there can be multiple "vacation"-posts) returned as json for some AJAX-handling.

For example I want an json array like this:

```
[ {
    "vacation_name"  : "summer",
    "vacation_start" : "01-07-2019",
    "vacation_end" : "30-07-2019"
  },
  {
    "vacation_name"  : "winter",
    "vacation_start" : "01-12-2019",
    "vacation_end" : "14-12-2019"
  },
]
```

or something like that...

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it with meta_query like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('ferieperioder'),
    'post_status' => array('publish'),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post__in' => $post->ID,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'vacation_start',
            'value' => $startDate,
            'type' => 'DATE',
            'compare' => '>='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'vacation_end',
            'value' => $endDate,
            'type' => 'DATE',
            'compare' => '<='
        ) 
    )   
);
```

Comment: The `value` is still null, something doesn't work regarding getting the custom fields :-/

Comment: You should pass a post id in the function and change the get_fields: `code`function get_vacation_dates($vacation_id){
  $startDate = get_field('vacation_start', $vacation_id);
  $endDate = get_field('vacation_end', $vacation_id);`code`